# Should my dependency go from class to interface or class to concrete type in this case for my UML diagram?

Tags: java, dependencies, uml

Say I have the following Java class. `Entity` is an interface, which is implemented by `ConcreteEntity`.  Should I have a dependency from `SomeClass` to `Entity` or `SomeClass` to `ConcreteEntity` in my UML diagram?

```
class SomeClass {
   Entity entity = new ConcreteEntity();

   public SomeClass() {

   }
}
```

Comment: As pointed out by Alexander Babin, it's a mistake to use `ConcreteEntity` in the constructor. You should better correct this.

Comment: I've edited my question, to better reflect what I was after without having the weird constructor. I believe the relationships given by querty_so's solutions still hold in this case.

Comment: But the issue ist still the same: it's a flaw to declare a variable/attribute with a type A that generalizes B, when it cannot have other values than from B.

Comment: @GerdWagner I'm a little confused by the issue. Isn't it quite common to do what I'm doing in my question when using the Factory method in OOP? As seen [here](https://github.com/iluwatar/java-design-patterns/tree/master/factory-method), this line: `Blacksmith blacksmith = new ElfBlacksmith();` is effectively what I'm doing in SomeClass. Isn't this valid?

Comment: Their use of the interface type in their assignment statement also does not make sense. They could also write: `ElfBlacksmith blacksmith = new ElfBlacksmith();` without making a difference. But hardwiring such an assignment in the attribute declaration of the class makes the use of the (more general) interface type completely superfluous..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your class diagram would look like this:

[image]

`SomeClass` has an owned property `entity` of type `Entity`. The latter is a general form of `ConcreteEntity`. Since that is used as parameter there's a dependency from `SomeClass`.

Comment: As pointed out by Alexander Babin, it's a mistake of the OP to use `ConcreteEntity` in the constructor. Therefore, there is no direct dependency of `SomeClass`  on `ConcreteEntity`. Otherwise, your answer is the correct one and would deserve an upvote or accept.

Comment: @GerdWagner Thanks for the hint, Gerd. I have to wait for the OP to  fix his question. Else it would feel strange to give the right answer to the wrong question ;-)

Comment: Isn't it the responsibility of an expert advisor to point out errors to his advisee, and not repeat their errors without any comment?

Comment: @GerdWagner Well, I don't know what the OP's intention is. Questions here are abbreviated and without context there's no guessing. So, where is the error?

Answer (score -1):

Your class has `Entity`. Therefore, there are no matter what concrete implementation will be used. So, in UML you should have dependency from `SomeClass` to `Entity`. But, additionaly, your UML will have relation between `Entity` and `ConcreteEntity` as implementation

Comment: And one more moment. IMHO, you should not have to use ConcreteEntity in constructor. Just change it to Entity. Otherwise your class-file should use added import. Actually, you use interface for unbind your class and concrete implementation of Entity. So, your class-code should have only Entity